# database connectivity not working in ajax call- laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

My javascript is:

```
$( "#exerciseFetch" ).change(function( event ) {   //alert("super");
    // var _token = $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val()

    var mytoken = $('#mytoken').attr('value');
    ajaxContent = [  
        {"_token": mytoken},
        {"val"  : $( "#exerciseFetch" ).val()}                            
    ]
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'exerciseFetchAjaxCall', 
        data: { ajaxContent }
        // data: { "_token": mytoken }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
        var reqContent = msg;
        $("#dynamic").html(reqContent);
    });
});
```

my route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Admin'), function()
{
    Route::post('exerciseFetchAjaxCall', 'ExerciseController@exerciseAjaxCall');
});
```

my controller code:

```
public function exerciseAjaxCall(){
    $row = $_POST['ajaxContent'];

    // $row[1]['val']

    $muscles = Muscular::whereIn('Status',array(1))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    // return    $this->content = View::make('admin.exercise.displayMusclarGroupAjax',array('row' => $row ));
    return $this->content = View::make('admin.exercise.displayMusclarGroupAjax',array('muscles' => $muscles ));
}
```

my view code:

```
@if($muscles && count($muscles) > 0)
    @foreach($muscles as $muscular)
    <?php

        $icons = ["fa-icon-user", "fa-icon-user", "fa-icon-user inactive"];    
        $typeArray = [
            '1'=> 'Resistance',
            '2'=> 'Cardio'
        ];
        $typeArray[3] = 'Resistance & Cardio';

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="muscular_name">{{ ucfirst($muscular->muscular_name) }}</td>
        <td data-title="muscular_type">{{ $typeArray[$muscular->type]}}</td>                        
    </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
    ?>
    @endforeach
@endif
@if(isset($row) && count($row) > 0)
    <?print_r($row);?>
@endif
```

If I comment out the row contents and comment the muscles content in controller the code returns the values passed but the contents of the muscles are not displayed if uncommented.

I have displayed the muscle contents with the same code in its listing page (but without ajax call) dont know why its not working as I am new to laravel.

Any suggestions would be helpful...

Comment: use Chrome Dev tool and post what error/response you got

Comment: @Saqueib there's nothing wrong with my java script it works fine but **there's something wrong in the controller or the view** but it doesn't gets displayed in the laravel debugger :(

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in ajax script, Try this simple `$.post()` api to make ajax call

```
 $( "#exerciseFetch" ).change(function( event ) {   //alert("super");
    // var _token = $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val()

    var mytoken = $('#mytoken').attr('value'),
        ajaxContent = {
           "_token" : mytoken,
           "val"  : $( "#exerciseFetch" ).val()
        };

    //make ajax call 
    $.post( "exerciseFetchAjaxCall", ajaxContent ).done(
        function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
            var reqContent = msg;
            $("#dynamic").html(reqContent);
        }
    );
});
```

Above should do, If nothing is returning from DB please try `dd()` in controller to see the returned result

```
//are you sure `Status` is not in small case 
$muscles = Muscular::whereIn('Status',array(1))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

dd($muscles);
```

Comment: Semi-colons in JavaScript aren't required, also not a syntax error.

Comment: its saying `SyntaxError: invalid object initializer` because of this `data: { ajaxContent }`

Comment: Which brings us back to the start: Which specific part of their code is causing the syntax error? I don't see how saying "You have a syntax error, try this totally changed code." is helpful for *teaching* them. Explain what part of their code is causing the syntax error and why, then explain what you've done to fix it.